# How to play H.265/HEVC videos?

Tags: codec, video-player

I cannot play H.265/HEVC videos. While trying to play video I get an error "Audience needs video/x-unknown decoder to play this file". Here's a screenshot of an error.

[image: error image]

If I click on install video decoder, again it gives me an error "plugin not found". How can solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a PPA for libde265 GStreamer integration.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265
sudo apt-get update
```

New install the plugin:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-libde265 gstreamer1.0-libde265
```

After installation of the plugin, all players using the GStreamer framework (this includes the default player “Videos”) will be able to playback HEVC/H.265 content.

There is also a VLC plugin available:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
```

Source: [GStreamer plugin for 4K H.265/HEVC video streaming](http://www.libde265.org/blog/2014/02/22/gstreamer-4k-h265-hevc-plugin/)

Comment: I'd like to install vlc plugin. I have added the suggested repo, but after `sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265` get  `E: Unable to locate package vlc-plugin-libde265` error. What could be the problem? (I'm on elementary OS 5, VLC 3.071)